# How to create my own custom nuget package for System.Data.SQLite to correctly include the interop dlls?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, system.data.sqlite, nuget-spec

I want to create my own custom package for System.Data.SQLite. I have the all the dll's I need but I'm unsure how to structure it and create the nuspec for it.
Current folder structure of the dll's is this, whereabouts would I put the different interop dlls to have them copied correctly to the output and what do I need to add to the nuspec?

```
lib/net452
  -> System.Data.SQLite.dll , System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll, System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll
Custom.SQLite.nuspec
```

Still have the default nuspec something like this atm

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/01/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata minClientVersion="2.5">
    <id>Custom.SQLite.Name</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <authors>name</authors>
    <owners>owner</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Desc</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2021</copyright>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLite.Interop.dll` does not act as a lib assembly dll. That is not its role. And it should be a content file rather than a assembly dll. So it should not be packed as `lib`.

To create such custom nuget package, you should first pack `System.Data.SQLite.dll`, `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll`, `System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll` as `lib`. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-assembly-files).

and then pack `SQLite.Interop.dll` as `content`.

**Also**, to make the content file be copied into the output folder of the main project when you install the nuget package, you have to use a <packages_id>.props or targets file to realize it.

**1)** create a file called <packages_id>.props into your class library project. And it should be the same name as your nuget package. In your side, it should be named as `Custom.SQLite.Name.props`. Otherwise, it will not work.

And then add these into the file:

```
<Project>

<ItemGroup>
<None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\content\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll">
<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\content\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll">
<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>

</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**2)** use this nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/01/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata minClientVersion="2.5">
    <id>Custom.SQLite.Name</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <authors>name</authors>
    <owners>owner</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Desc</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2021</copyright>
  </metadata>
<files>
<file src="System.Data.SQLite.dll" target="lib\net452" />
<file src="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll" target="lib\net452" />
<file src="System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll" target="lib\net452" />
<file src="xxx\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" target="content\x86" />
<file src="xxx\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll" target="content\x64" />
<file src="Custom.SQLite.Name.props" target="build" />

</files>
</package>
```

**3)** rebuild your lib project and then use nuget pack to pack the new version.

**Before** you use this new version, please uninstall the old one and delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\Custom.SQLite.Name` and `<solution_folder>\packages\Custom.SQLite.Name.1.0.0`. Then, reinstall the new version.

Comment: Doing this just leads to an error when I try to use the package.

Failed to add reference to 'SQLite.Interop'.
Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Comment: Ohh. Sorry for that I am knowing that SQLite.Interop.dll does not act as a lib assembly dll. That is not its role. Really sorry for that. And it should be a content file rather than a assembly dll. So it should not be packed as lib. I will update my answer

Comment: What is your vs version? And nuget.exe version? I will update tomorrow.

Comment: No worries, I did what you suggested and made it content file and it worked great, so thanks!